# Remove an item from a list by shifting all other elements

Tags: php

I want to remove a value from a list to a randomly selected id and shift all element content according to the list is shorter than 1 .

Comment: show us code  where to do?

Comment: What is "a list"? PHP has arrays - is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: What have you tried?? Edit your original question and post the code you have tried. You can edit your question by clicking the _**edit**_ link

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can achieve this using [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) and [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

**PHP**

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 5];
array_splice($array, array_rand($array), 1);
```

Comment: OP is interested with list not array

Comment: As OP did't give any resource than why we help OP. Are we do job here???

Comment: You should not provide an answer to someone who does not show an attempt of trying out to figure out the problem. Push for them to provide some code they have tried.